# Квантификаторы в vim

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vim

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать следующее: по нажатию F7 vim подсвечивает все парные пробелы в начале каждой строки. Разумеется, что для того чтоб их подсветить, их надо сначала найти. Использование такой регулярки не дает профита:

```
/^(\s\s)+
```

Как быть?

Comment: А почему не так?

    /^\s\s

Comment: @Дож Потому что так светит только первые два пробела и все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Забыли несколько бэкслешей:

```
/^\(\s\s\)\+
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать **\v** для упрощения выражения:

```
/\v^(\s\s)+
```